# How to remove specific records based on column pattern

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like this:

| event | value | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| seed | 57 | 2021-08-01 09:49:23 |
| ghy | 869 | 2021-08-02 09:50:12 |
| repo | 5324 | 2021-09-03 10:49:23 |
| repo | null | 2021-09-03 11:49:23 |
| harv | 12 | 2021-09-05 09:43:23 |
| weig | 5,37,12 | 2021-09-06 09:25:12 |
| repo | null,null,4,8 | 2021-09-07 09:12:23 |
| repo | 4,8,null,null | 2021-09-07 10:49:23 |
| repo | null,null,4,8 | 2021-09-08 17:49:23 |
| repo | 4,8,1,3 | 2021-09-09 12:12:23 |
| repo | 1356 | 2021-09-10 12:49:23 |

Sometimes the `value` column has the following pattern: `null, null, x, y`, where x and y are any natural numbers.

Do you know how to delete all pairs of records from the diagram: `x, y, null, null` and then again `null, null, x, y` **immediately after the first occurrence** of such a pattern?

I mean the expected output should be:

| event | value | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| seed | 57 | 2021-08-01 09:49:23 |
| ghy | 869 | 2021-08-02 09:50:12 |
| repo | 5324 | 2021-09-03 10:49:23 |
| repo | null | 2021-09-03 11:49:23 |
| harv | 12 | 2021-09-05 09:43:23 |
| weig | 5,37,12 | 2021-09-06 09:25:12 |
| repo | null,null,4,8 | 2021-09-07 09:12:23 |
| repo | 4,8,1,3 | 2021-09-09 12:12:23 |
| repo | 1356 | 2021-09-10 12:49:23 |

When according to one of the answers, I use it:

```
import numpy as np

df['value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x : ','.join(np.sort(x.split(','))))

df.drop_duplicates(['value'], keep='first')
```

I get:

| event | value | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| seed | 57 | 2021-08-01 09:49:23 |
| ghy | 869 | 2021-08-02 09:50:12 |
| repo | 5324 | 2021-09-03 10:49:23 |
| repo | null | 2021-09-03 11:49:23 |
| harv | 12 | 2021-09-05 09:43:23 |
| weig | **12,37,5** | 2021-09-06 09:25:12 |
| repo | **4,8,null,null** | 2021-09-07 09:12:23 |
| repo | 4,8,1,3 | 2021-09-09 12:12:23 |
| repo | 1356 | 2021-09-10 12:49:23 |

Some of the values ​​in the 'value' column change their positions (see bold).

Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: it is removed, because same pattern `null,null,4,8`, `4,8,null,null` and `null,null,4,8` has same numbers, here `4,8` ? If `null,null,4,8`, `1,0,null,null` and `4,8,null,null`  is removed only last  `4,8,null,null` ?

Comment: @jezrael yes, exactly like that, they should only be removed if they have the same x, y numbers

Comment: value in `value column` is list or string?

Comment: `value` is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because element in `value column` is string. you can `.split()` them and sort them with `np.sort` then back them to string and use `drop_duplicates()` like below.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

df['value2'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x : ','.join(np.sort(x.split(','))))

df.drop_duplicates(['value2'], keep='first')
```

Comment: Ah! It was a good idea, now it works fine :) Thanks a lot