# Removing specific records based on sequences of value in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

According to case: [How to remove specific records based on column pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69434511/how-to-remove-specific-records-based-on-column-pattern)

Right now I have another issue.
Example of `df` table:

| event | value | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| seed | 57 | 2021-08-01 09:49:23 |
| ghy | 869 | 2021-08-02 09:50:12 |
| repo | 5324 | 2021-09-03 10:49:23 |
| repo | null | 2021-09-03 11:49:23 |
| harv | 12 | 2021-09-05 09:43:23 |
| weig | 5,37,12 | 2021-09-06 09:25:12 |
| repo | null,null,4,8 | 2021-09-07 09:12:23 |
| repo | 4,8,null,null | 2021-09-07 10:49:23 |
| repo | null,null,4,8 | 2021-09-08 17:49:23 |
| repo | 4,8,1,3 | 2021-09-09 12:12:23 |
| repo | 1356 | 2021-09-10 12:49:23 |

I would like  to remove records after specific value, contains pattern: `null,null,x,y`, but only when I can find sequence: `null,null,x,y` , `x,y,null,null` and again `null,null,x,y`.

`x, y` are any natural numbers. Column `value` is a string.

E.g. for the `value` sequence:

`null,null,1,3`
`1,3,null,null`
`null,null,1,3` - the last two values ​​(records) should be deleted.

Based on this above, expected output should looks like this:

| event | value | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| seed | 57 | 2021-08-01 09:49:23 |
| ghy | 869 | 2021-08-02 09:50:12 |
| repo | 5324 | 2021-09-03 10:49:23 |
| repo | null | 2021-09-03 11:49:23 |
| harv | 12 | 2021-09-05 09:43:23 |
| weig | 5,37,12 | 2021-09-06 09:25:12 |
| repo | null,null,4,8 | 2021-09-07 09:12:23 |
| repo | 4,8,1,3 | 2021-09-09 12:12:23 |
| repo | 1356 | 2021-09-10 12:49:23 |

However, if I have for example table like this one:

| event | value | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| seed | 57 | 2021-08-01 09:49:23 |
| ghy | 869 | 2021-08-02 09:50:12 |
| repo | 5324 | 2021-09-03 10:49:23 |
| repo | null | 2021-09-03 11:49:23 |
| harv | 12 | 2021-09-05 09:43:23 |
| weig | 5,37,12 | 2021-09-06 09:25:12 |
| repo | null,null,4,8 | 2021-09-07 09:12:23 |
| repo | 4,8,null,null | 2021-09-07 10:49:23 |
| repo | 4,8,1,3 | 2021-09-09 12:12:23 |
| repo | 1356 | 2021-09-10 12:49:23 |

There is no modification needed (because the sequence of three values ​​is not preserved).

I'm new to Python and stuck on these table modifications. I will be grateful for any idea.

Comment: The accepted answer will delete the last two rows of group even when the numbers are not same. i.e. if there is a group such as null,null,1,2 ----  4,5,null,null ----- null,null,34 it will delete last two rows. is this the desired behavior? or you want the numbers to be same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first thought of `DataFrame.rolling`; however, it doesn't accept string column.  So I made use of `DataFrame.shift` twice to group the previous two values together:

```
#DataFrame initialization
data = {
'event': ['seed', 'ghy', 'repo', 'repo', 'harv', 'weig', 'repo', 'repo', 'repo', 'repo', 'repo'],
'value' :['57', '869', '5324', 'null', '12', '5,37,12', 'null,null,4,8', '4,8,null,null', 'null,null,4,8', '4,8,1,3', '1356'],
'time': ['1/8/2021 9:49', '2/8/2021 9:50', '3/9/2021 10:49', '3/9/2021 11:49', '5/9/2021 9:43', '6/9/2021 9:25', '7/9/2021 9:12', '7/9/2021 10:49', '8/9/2021 17:49', '9/9/2021 12:12', '10/9/2021 12:49']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])


#Processing
patterns = [r'null,null,\d+,\d+',
            r'\d+,\d+,null,null',
            r'null,null,\d+,\d+',]

screening = 0
for pos, pat in enumerate(patterns):
  screening += df['value'].shift(pos).str.contains(pat)
screening = (screening == 3)
df = df[~(screening | screening.shift(-1))]
print(df)
```

Comment: I struggled with it for half a day.. Works perfect, thanks a lot!